# Dynamic tree algorithm using JS

Tags: javascript, dynamic, tree

-init Data

```
{
sport: ['s_1', 's_2', 's_3'],
date: ['d_1', 'd_2'],
category: ['c_1']
}
```

- Input data (dynamic with fields)

['sport', 'date'] or ['sport', 'date', 'category']

- Output data

If input data = ['sport', 'date']

: output have to show below.

```
[
's_1',
's_1|d_1',
's_1|d_2',
's_2',
's_2|d_1',
's_2|d_2',
's_3',
's_3|d_1',
's_3|d_2'
]
```

If input data = ['sport', 'date', 'category']

: output have to show below.

```
['s_1',
's_1|d_1',
's_1|d_1|c_1',
's_1|d_2',
's_1|d_2|c_1'
's_2',
's_2|d_1',
's_2|d_1|c_1',
's_2|d_2',
's_2|d_2|c_1',
's_3',
's_3|d_1',
's_3|d_1|c_1',
's_3|d_2',
's_3|d_2|c_1'
]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is the question here? Take a read over the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help construct a good question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```js
var data = {sport: ['s_1', 's_2', 's_3'], date: ['d_1', 'd_2'], category: ['c_1']}
function* combos(d, c = []){
    if (c.length > 0){
       yield c.join('|')
    }
    if (d.length > 0){
        for (var i of data[d[0]]){
            yield* combos(d.slice(1), [...c, i])
        }
    }
}
console.log([...combos(['sport', 'date'])]) 
console.log([...combos(['sport', 'date', 'category'])])
```